# Cheerio get nested div element

Tags: javascript, cheerio

Im using **Cheerio** to try to get a value in a nested child element. The value is the $7.38 as shown in the HTML below. As shown, it is in the last div element, of the first child div element, of the div class "stock-dcf-table"

My code is below. Right now I can get the first child element of the div class. But I need to get the last div element of this child element, where the value is. How do I get there?

I'm using Cheerio so I have to use Cheerio's syntax and functions.

I have tried my code below and it works for another table on the same webpage. But I can't seem to get this value. Can someone help me out here please? I have tried the other cheerio code answers on SO too. Thanks.

[image: html source]

```html
 var url = 'https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/drh/dcf';
  
const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
const $ = Cheerio.load(content);

const data = $('.stock-dcf-table').children().first().text();
Logger.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the children of `first()` and find last element and then get text.

Try this

```
const data = $('.stock-dcf-table').children().first().children().last().text();
```